# JS codes dosen't work in loaded content, when using jquery ajax load function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, load

I have 2 page, 1.first.html, 2.second.html (with simple html markup).
in both page, I have a div#container.

I linked the .js files (jquery, app, plugins) in both pages, in bottom on the page)
I have an anchor link in first.html (linked to second.html), and I handled the click event on the anchor with jquery, my code looks like below:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('#container').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #container');
});
```

the above code, working, but the js codes (for loaded content) not working. (for example I used a validation plugin in second.html, or submitting some data using ajax in second.html)
the point is, if I redirect to second.html (not using ajax), all codes working correctly !

Below is the text, from api.jquery.com, about load function:

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed

How I can fix this problem? any alternative way? or ...

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply load your scripts in the first page? Have everything ready to go for when the second page's content is loaded in.

Comment: imaging, I have a textbox in second.html, I added a validation plugin for that, when I use load method, this plugin doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it depends on your validation plugin, but you modify your code to run the validation setup *after* you have loaded in the second content. Essentially you are creating a SPA architecture with 'views' being loaded in - your JS needs/should live in one file.

Comment: thanks for answering man, in my real project, second page is a data entry page, I posting data using ajax, please note, I putted all my js codes, in app.js, how I can run this code in first page? (when I loaded #container from second page)

Comment: if you like the answer, mark it ;) so im not sure i get your question. if $("#form").validateSetup() is for your second page, run it in your success handler for loading in the second page. ie, after loading, do whatever makes sense.

Comment: I told the validation just for an example, if in the second page, I just had a button, and handling the CLICK event with jquery, when I loaded second page, in first, using load function, this code not working

Comment: Remember that if you do $("selector") and it isn't there, it won't work. Use the .on method instead. It can handle DOM items loaded later. Check jQuery docs for on() for details.

Comment: If you refer to api.jquery (i wrote at end of my first post, the question in fact), you can see load function fired this problem. I use ID that I have that already on the content, also always use on keyword for binding event to selectors. the problem is: all js codes be inactive, when using load method to load content. please note, if I use just $('#container').load($(this).attr('href'));, all will work correctly. because I loaded the .js files, again